# Can the execution of statements in Python be delayed?

Tags: python, sleep, delay, timing

I want it to run the first line **print 1** then wait 1 second to run the second command **print 2**, etc.

Pseudo-code:

```
print 1
wait(1 seconds)
print 2
wait(0.45 seconds)
print 3
wait(3 seconds)
print 4
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[`time.sleep(seconds)`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html)

```
import time

print 1
time.sleep(1)
print 2
time.sleep(0.45)
print 3
time.sleep(3)
print 4
```

Answer (score 16):

All the answers have assumed that you want or can manually insert `time.sleep` after each line, but may be you want a automated way to do that for a large number of lines of code e.g. consider this code

```
def func1():
    print "func1 1",time.time()
    print "func1 2",time.time()

def func2():
    print "func2 1",time.time()
    print "func2 2",time.time()

def main():
    print 1,time.time()
    print 2,time.time()
    func1()
    func2()
```

If you want to delay execution of each line, either you can manually insert `time.sleep` before each line which is cumbersome and error-prone, instead you can use `sys.settrace` to get you own function called before each line is executed and in that callback you can delay execution, so without manually inserting `time.sleep` at every place and littering code, you can do this instead

```
import sys
import time

def func1():
    print "func1 1",time.time()
    print "func1 2",time.time()

def func2():
    print "func2 1",time.time()
    print "func2 2",time.time()

def main():
    print 1,time.time()
    print 2,time.time()
    func1()
    func2()

def mytrace(frame, event, arg):
    if event == "line":
        time.sleep(1)
    return mytrace

sys.settrace(mytrace)
main()
```

Without trace output is:

```
1 1280032100.88
2 1280032100.88
func1 1 1280032100.88
func1 2 1280032100.88
func2 1 1280032100.88
func2 2 1280032100.88
```

With trace output is:

```
1 1280032131.27
2 1280032132.27
func1 1 1280032134.27
func1 2 1280032135.27
func2 1 1280032137.27
func2 2 1280032138.27
```

You can further tweak it according to your needs, may be checking line contents too and most importantly this is very easy to disable and will work with any code.

Answer (score 5):

```
import time

# ...

time.sleep(1)
```